# View/Controller for Destroying a has_many :through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations, has-many-through, controllers

I've got Users, Teams, and TeamMemberships, which are associated with a has_many :through.

I'm trying add the ability to remove a User from a Team, which requires destroying the TeamMembership model that associates them.

My Models are as follows:

```
# models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :members, :through => :team_memberships
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_memberships
end

# models/team_membership.rb
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

The view currently looks like this:

```
- @team.members.each do |member|
  .member
    = link_to member.name, user_path(member)
    = button_to "Remove User"
```

I'm looking for help with finishing the implementation for the "Remove User" button. I'm not sure how to pass in the TeamMembership that I need to destroy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :teams do
    resources :users do
        member do
            delete :remove_from_team
        end
    end
end
```

In the users controller:

```
def remove_from_team
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id]) #can do that in before_filter
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    @team.members.delete user
    redirect_to @team
end
```

In the view

```
= button_to "Remove user", remove_from_team_team_user_path(@team, member), :method => :delete
```

---

You could also just have

```
resources :team_memberships
```

And have a destroy action in the team_memberships controller

```
= button_to "Remove user", team_membership_path(@team.team_memberships.where(:user_id => member.id).first), :method => :delete
```

But there would be a query needed to get the team_membership for each member even if the user never click the link...

Comment: Thanks. I went with the second option since I already had a team_memberships controller. 

The only thing is to make sure that you pass in the TeamMembership itself rather than the ActiveRecord::Relation.

So I used team_membership_path(@team.team_memberships.where(user_id: member.id).first